# Is it possible to use existing mail accounts settings?

Tags: ios, email, settings

Is it possible to get existing account settings from ios? I would like to prompt a select box to users so that they can choose an account they already created in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need that ? There is no way to do that.

There is a field called `From` in `MFMailComposeViewController`. You can choose the needed account from there.

**Note:**

This field is visible when multiple mail accounts are added in Setting App.